# getopt always returns 1

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, getopt

I want to use `getopt` to get the argument list of my console tool.
When I call my tool like below `getopt` returns always `1` and doesn't mactch any `switch/case`.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
  mytool -f farg -d darg

  int 
  main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int c;
  while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "f:d:h") != -1)) {

      switch(c) {
        case'f':
        break;

        default:
        break;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "f:d:h") != -1))
```

It works like

```
c = (getopt(argc, argv, "f:d:h") != -1)
```

Well, that is 1 always because the result of the comparison is stored to `c`. In your case the `getopt` does not return `-1`. If it returns `-1` then `c` would be `0`. The fix is

```
while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "f:d:h")) != -1)
```